# First-class functions with type parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a first-class function with type parameter like below
and getting an error, Sure the answer is simple.

Any idea if this is possible in scala and how to do this?

```
var increase = [T](x: T) => x + 1
println(increase(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define an anonymous function with a type parameter.

Instead, you can define increase as a method:

```
def increase[T: Numeric](x: T, y: T): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)
```

And then call it

```
println(increase(10, 1))
```

Comment: You can call it a limitation, but it's currently not possible.

Comment: Ok, I see, its more to encourage people to define specific signature for method. Thanks!

Comment: See [this blog post](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've manage to find it: "There are some other differences between methods and functions. A method can be type-parameterized, but an anonymous function can not:" ...

Comment: Shapeless has polymorphic function values... https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Comment: @Jasper Right, but there's still no *native* support.